# Cannot PATCH (.findByIdAndUpdate is not a function)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update a mongoDB database document for my To-Do list, I'm using Node, Mongoose, Express and Express Router.

Mongoose Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const toDoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    value: {
        type: String,
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
    },
    _id: {
        type: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('toDo', toDoSchema)
```

Patch code:

```
router.patch('/changeCategory', async (request, response) =>{
    
    const updateItem = new toDoModel({
        category: request.body.category
    })

    let id = request.body._id
    let category = request.body.category
    
    try{
        await updateItem.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: id},{category: category})
        response.json('Category changed')
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error.message)
    }
})
```

Insomnia request:

```
PATCH http://localhost:5000/changeCategory
{
    "category":"inProgress",
    "_id": "628de6210da8e45f52217083"
}
```

and what i get is "updateItem.findByIdAndUpdate is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

This way is wrong. because you can't use `findByIdAndUpdate` with `updateItem` variable ..if you want use `findByIdAndUpdate`, you should use the imported model, then use this method.

example code:

```
const toDoModel = require("../models/your-model")

router.patch('/changeCategory', async (request, response) => {
  let category = request.body.category
  const updateItem = new toDoModel({
    category
  })

  let id = request.body._id

  try {
    // This part was changed *****

    await toDoModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{category: category})
    response.json('Category changed')

    // *******
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  }
})
```

I hope this solution helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in my previous code when i had used the .save() and .deleteOne() methods i had used them on the variable created from the new model so thought i was to use this again here. I had tried using it on the actual model itself as you suggested in your answer and hadn't worked but did a major overhaul of my code and is now working as you suggested
But as I understand it I can delete the variable completely as I'm not using it?
thanks for your help!